# problem with jquery.form.js and preventing event propagation

Tags: jquery, events, stoppropagation

I'm working on a single-page site with sliding content.

I'm using jquery.form.js and am using the following in the head to initialise the contact form/script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $('#closeit').click(function(){
    $('.message').hide('slow');
    return false;
    });

    var options = { 
    target:        '#alert',
    }; 

    $('#contactForm').bind('submit', function() {
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    });


    $.fn.clearForm = function() {
      return this.each(function() {
        var type = this.type, tag = this.tagName.toLowerCase();
        if (tag == 'form')
          return $(':input',this).clearForm();
        if (type == 'text' || type == 'password' || tag == 'textarea')
          this.value = '';
        else if (type == 'checkbox' || type == 'radio')
          this.checked = false;
        else if (tag == 'select')
          this.selectedIndex = -1;
      });
    };  
</script>
```

I'm also using the following to prevent event propagation when the user clicks anywhere within the form:

```
$(function() {
    $('#email-form').click(fillForm);
});
function fillForm(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
}
```

But when I click the 'submit' button, the form is not submitted. I can't think how to fix this so that the form is submitted without the event bubbling.

Any guidance/assistance would be much appreciated.

MTIA.

(Here's my form for the record:)

```
<form action="sendmemail.php" method="post" id="contactForm">
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="field-row">
            <div class="field-name"><p>name:<span class="abbrev">*</span></div>
            <div class="field-box"><input type="text" class="allfields" name="name" id="name"/></div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="field-row">
            <div class="field-name"><p>email:<span class="abbrev">*</span></div>
            <div class="field-box"><input type="text" class="allfields" name="email" id="email"/></div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="field-row">
            <div class="field-name"><p>phone:<span class="abbrev">*</span></div>
            <div class="field-box"><input type="text" class="allfields" name="tele" id="tele"/></div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="field-row message-field">
            <div class="field-name"><p>message:<span class="abbrev">*</span></div>
            <div class="field-box">
                <textarea class="allfields messagetext" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="submitbutton">
        <input type="submit" name="submitbutton" id="submitbutton" value=" SUBMIT" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: not sure if this is just a typo here or if its in your actual code - but youre missing the arg definition (e.g. `e`) for your submit handler. Also do you want to specifically stop propagation or do you just want to prevent the default handling of the event?

Comment: well, that's a good question. i'm pretty new to jquery and in this case, i'm not sure what the default event handling is. The form sits in a #content div. If the user clicks on #content, the site slides. So is the default event handling the site sliding, or the form submission? In any case, I want to stop the site sliding and I want to submit the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is user gonna submit form if you even forbid him to click using your

```
$(function() {
    $('#email-form').click(fillForm);
});
function fillForm(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Yep, removed `return false` and it seems to be working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the example of ajaxSubmit on the jquery.form.js homepage?
http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxSubmit

```
$('#contactForm').submit(function() { 
    // inside event callbacks 'this' is the DOM element so we first 
    // wrap it in a jQuery object and then invoke ajaxSubmit 
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 

    // !!! Important !!! 
    // always return false to prevent standard browser submit and page navigation 
    return false; 
});
```

I don't know what events you are expecting when clicking in the form, but the fact that you are stopping propagation of events in the form may lead to stop the click on the button as well.